# c# parse html using XPathDocument

Tags: c#, xpath, html-parsing

i'm trying to parse an html page with XPathDocument, but gives error 'cause the html is not an xml...
is there a way to do this or not?

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex). Still the best!

Answer (score 3):

Use something like [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) which can load your html into a DOM object which can be traversed with for example xpath queries.

Unless your html is in fact xhtml, it is usually not a valid xml structure with correct opening and ending node tags.

Comment: I would like to mark this answer up, but htmlagilitypack does not work with the doc I'm giving it, the LoadFile() method does not have a return value, and does not throw an exception either. The document appears to not return anything when I query it either, so I'm assuming the code has "silently failed" when this happens?

Comment: Hi @ConradB, Have you tried the sample at http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples? Load should not return anything, but it should make you able to loop over nodes doing selections.